# reshape from base vs dcast from reshape2 with missing values

Tags: r, reshape, missing-data, reshape2

Whis this data frame,

```
df <- expand.grid(id="01", parameter=c("blood", "saliva"), visit=c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
df$value <- c(1:6)
df$sex <- rep("f", 6)
df

> df
  id parameter visit value sex
1 01     blood    V1     1   f
2 01    saliva    V1     2   f
3 01     blood    V2     3   f
4 01    saliva    V2     4   f
5 01     blood    V3     5   f
6 01    saliva    V3     6   f
```

When I reshape it in the "wide" format, I get identical results with both the base `reshape` function and the `dcast` function from `reshape2`.

```
reshape(df,
        timevar="visit",
        idvar=c("id", "parameter", "sex"),
        direction="wide")

  id parameter sex value.V1 value.V2 value.V3
1 01     blood   f        1        3        5
2 01    saliva   f        2        4        6


library(reshape2)
dcast(df,
      id+parameter+sex~visit,
      value.var="value")

  id parameter sex V1 V2 V3
1 01     blood   f  1  3  5
2 01    saliva   f  2  4  6
```

But if I add some missing values, the results differs

```
df$value <- c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA)
df$sex <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
df

> df
  id parameter visit value sex
1 01     blood    V1     1  NA
2 01    saliva    V1     2  NA
3 01     blood    V2    NA  NA
4 01    saliva    V2    NA  NA
5 01     blood    V3    NA  NA
6 01    saliva    V3    NA  NA
```

With base `reshape`, I get only one row

```
reshape(df,
        timevar="visit",
        idvar=c("id", "parameter", "sex"),
        direction="wide")

  id parameter sex value.V1 value.V2 value.V3
1 01     blood  NA        1       NA       NA
```

With `dcast`, I get two rows

```
dcast(df,
      id+parameter+sex~visit,
      value.var="value")

  id parameter sex V1 V2 V3
1 01     blood  NA  1 NA NA
2 01    saliva  NA  2 NA NA
```

Is there a way to handle these missing values in the base `reshape` function, as I'd like to use this one?

Comment: From the help page, it is not obvious that how the `reshape` handles with the missing values.

Comment: But where goes the non-`NA`-value `2`?

Comment: That's the point. I'd like to know where it goes!

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug, but if you replace the NA in `sex` to any other value, for example `0`, it gives the 2 rows.

Comment: This is what I noticed as well. In the first example the value of `sex` is set to `f` and it causes no problem. That's why I guess the issue comes from the `NA`.

Comment: In the code it use `missing(idvar) &&`.. probably it is a bug, but at least you are getting the output with `dcast` which is also not very confusing.

Comment: Sure, it's fine with `dcast`, I'm just used to `reshape`. Thanks for pointing out the `missing` argument in the code. I'll try to dig into that direction.

Comment: I didn't realise, but the `missing` argument is not linked to to missing values, i.e. `NA` but is only used to check whether an argument has been provided in the function call...

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of the `reshape` code would be the line:

```
data[, tempidname] <- interaction(data[, idvar], drop = TRUE)
```

Look at how `interaction` works:

```
> interaction("A", "B")
[1] A.B
Levels: A.B
> interaction("A", "B", NA)
[1] <NA>
Levels:
```

But, compare what would happen if `NA` were retained as a `level`:

```
> interaction("A", "B", addNA(NA))
[1] A.B.NA
Levels: A.B.NA
```

Thus, if you want to have the same result with base R's `reshape`, you need to make sure that any "idvar" columns have `NA` retained as a level.

Example:

```
df$sex <- addNA(df$sex)
reshape(df,
        timevar="visit",
        idvar=c("id", "parameter", "sex"),
        direction="wide")
#   id parameter  sex value.V1 value.V2 value.V3
# 1 01     blood <NA>        1       NA       NA
# 2 01    saliva <NA>        2       NA       NA
```

---

Of course, the other question is how `NA` can be treated as an identifying variable :-)