# reshape to wide with empty column returns only one observation

Tags: r, reshape

I noticed an empty column would end up resulting in only observation. Could someone explain this behavior to me? Should I just look for and drop empty columns before proceeding?

```
testdf <- CO2[,c("Plant","conc","Treatment","uptake")]

testdf$Plant <- gsub("c","n",testdf$Plant)

works <- reshape(
  testdf,
  idvar = c(
    "Plant",
    "conc"
  ),
  timevar = "Treatment",
  direction = "wide"
)

testdf$Problem <- as.numeric(NA)

notworking <- reshape(
  testdf,
  idvar = c(
    "Plant",
    "conc",
    "Problem"
  ),
  timevar = "Treatment",
  direction = "wide"
)
```

Comment: See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45639057/1270695) which shows how using `addNA` can help (without removing the "problem" column) -- and which references the same line in the `reshape` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line no '94' in `reshape` code could be causing the trouble

```
...
data[, tempidname] <- interaction(data[, idvar], 
            drop = TRUE)
...
```

Using the 'testdf'

```html
interaction(testdf[, c("Plant", "conc", "Problem")], drop = TRUE)
# [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#[23] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#[45] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#[67] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#Levels:
```

results in all `NA`.

Removing the 'Problem' column

```
interaction(testdf[, c("Plant", "conc")], drop = TRUE)
#[1] Qn1.95   Qn1.175  Qn1.250  Qn1.350  Qn1.500  Qn1.675  Qn1.1000 Qn2.95   Qn2.175  Qn2.250  Qn2.350  Qn2.500 
#[13] Qn2.675  Qn2.1000 Qn3.95   Qn3.175  Qn3.250  Qn3.350  Qn3.500  Qn3.675  Qn3.1000 Qn1.95   Qn1.175  Qn1.250 
#[25] Qn1.350  Qn1.500  Qn1.675  Qn1.1000 Qn2.95   Qn2.175  Qn2.250  Qn2.350  Qn2.500  Qn2.675  Qn2.1000 Qn3.95  
#[37] Qn3.175  Qn3.250  Qn3.350  Qn3.500  Qn3.675  Qn3.1000 Mn1.95   Mn1.175  Mn1.250  Mn1.350  Mn1.500  Mn1.675 
#[49] Mn1.1000 Mn2.95   Mn2.175  Mn2.250  Mn2.350  Mn2.500  Mn2.675  Mn2.1000 Mn3.95   Mn3.175  Mn3.250  Mn3.350 
#[61] Mn3.500  Mn3.675  Mn3.1000 Mn1.95   Mn1.175  Mn1.250  Mn1.350  Mn1.500  Mn1.675  Mn1.1000 Mn2.95   Mn2.175 
#[73] Mn2.250  Mn2.350  Mn2.500  Mn2.675  Mn2.1000 Mn3.95   Mn3.175  Mn3.250  Mn3.350  Mn3.500  Mn3.675  Mn3.1000
#42 Levels: Mn1.95 Mn2.95 Mn3.95 Qn1.95 Qn2.95 Qn3.95 Mn1.175 Mn2.175 Mn3.175 Qn1.175 Qn2.175 Qn3.175 ... Qn3.1000
```

---

Alternate approach includes `dcast` from either `reshape2` or `data.table`

```
data.table::dcast(testdf, Plant + conc + Problem ~ Treatment, value.var = 'uptake')
```

Or `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(testdf, Treatment, uptake)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, dcast works as expected. I need to learn how to debug functions.